# Deployed war file not working in external tomcat 10: unable to start web server in deploying war file in webapps folder

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, war

Deployed war file not working in external tomcat 10

It's just a simple test with jsp page and spring boot

Software:
Eclispe IDE (ultima versione)
Java 17
Tomcat 10
SpringBoot 3.1
Maven

Details
-0.Error
-1.pom
-2.project structure
-3.source code

-0.Error  (from tomcat console)____________________________________

Error when starting external tomcat server

w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 252 ms
2023-09-11T16:18:20.661+02:00  WARN 23272 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-09-11T16:18:20.661+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-11T16:18:20.708+02:00 ERROR 23272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at ......

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context. Possibly already registered? at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean.register(DynamicRegistrationBean.java:122) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]

```
___________________________________________________________________

-1.pom ____________________________________________________________
__

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.azienda</groupId>
    <artifactId>GaTomcat05w</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>GaTomcat05w</name>
    <description>GaTomcat05w</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add jakarta packages -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
         <finalName>GaTomcat05w</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
___________________________________________________________________

-2.project structure_______________________________________________

[project structure][1]

___________________________________________________________________

-3.source code_____________________________________________________

application.properties
----------------------
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

controller
---------

package com.azienda;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GaTomcat04Controller {
    @GetMapping("/helloc")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World",
        required = true) String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }
}

application
------------

package com.azienda;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GaTomcat05w extends  ServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GaTomcat05w.class, args);
    }

}

package com.azienda;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GaTomcat05w.class);
    }

}

jsp
--------
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<body>Ciao</body>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>



___________________________________________________________________

All works in embedded tomacat in eclipse ide. 
Problems starts in external tomcat.

I have already followed as mentioned in
 https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment


I'm new at this technology, any help would be very appreciate.
Thanks in advance
Andrea


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb4x1.png
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, format your questtion properly.

Comment: FAIL - Application at context path [/GaTomcat05w] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GaTomcat05w]]]

Comment: I improved my format question, hoping it's enough undestandably.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today and what worked for me was this configuration

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>backend_2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>backend-3</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>10.1.17</tomcat.version>
    <spring-security.version>6.0.0</spring-security.version>
</properties>
```

I was previously working with Spring Boot 3.2.1 and Spring Security 6.2.1, but I think that was a bit too ambitious at this point, so I've downgraded to slightly prior version of these.

In the manager view for Apache Tomcat 10, your deployed WAR will fail to start and you'll see this message in the logs as the specific cause:
[image]

Note that after this fix, your project will start, but may result in 403 authorization issue that I am still debugging.